# Fetch and store output from a subprocess in Java

Tags: java, subprocess, runtime.exec

I'm working on something that requires me to start to subprocess(command prompt) and execute some commands on it. I need to fetch the output from the subprocess and store it in a file or String.
here's what I have done so far, and it doesn't work:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        try
    {
        Runtime RT = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String command = "cmd /c start javap java.lang.String"; 
        File file = new File("write.txt");
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            BufferedReader br = new(BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(RT.exec(command).getInputStream()));
        String temp = br.readLine();
        while(!temp.equals(null))
        {
            output.write(temp);
            temp = br.readLine();
        }
        output.close();
        RT.exec("exit");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: _doesn't work_ as in what? what's the error ? what did you expect ? be more detailed

Comment: like I want that when the new command prompt opens and executes javap java.lang.String, that should get stored in write.txt . But all I get is a blank write.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Start changing this:</strike>

```
new(BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(
```

To:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
```

Compile and see if you still have the problem

**edit**

Also, there is a good reason why you shouldn't catch Exception, you also catch programming errors like a `NullPointerException`

```
 while( !temp.equals(null)) { //Throws NullPointerExceptin when temp is null
```

Change it with:

```
 while( temp != null ) { //!temp.equals(null)) {
```

Finally you don't have to "exit" since you're not inside the cmd really.

**Corrected version**

This version runs as you intend:

```
import java.io.*;
class Rt { 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          Runtime RT = Runtime.getRuntime();
          String  command =  "javap java.lang.String" ; 
          File file = new File("write.txt");
          Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(RT.exec(command).getInputStream()));
          String temp = br.readLine();
          while( temp != null ) { //!temp.equals(null)) {
              output.write(temp);
              temp = br.readLine();
          }
          output.close();
          //RT.exec("exit");
  }
}
```

**edit** 
Final remarks:

Since Java 1.5 the preferred way to invoke a command is using [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and it is better if you use an array of strings instead of a single string ( or varargs ).

When you're building your output you can get rid of the file object and pass the file name directly to the filewriter.

While reading the line you can assign and evaluate in the condition.

Java's coding conventions suggest to use the opening brace in the same like.

This would be my version of your code:

```
class Rt { 
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      Writer output     = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter ( "write.txt"));
      InputStream in    = new ProcessBuilder("javap", "java.lang.String").start().getInputStream();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in)); 
      String line = null;
      while( ( line = br.readLine() )   != null ) {
          output.write( line );
      }
      output.close();
  }
}
```

It might need still some work, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: sorry,it was a mistake in copying my code down here :)
the problem persists :)

Comment: @Kazekage You had a number of errors in your original code. See the **corrected version** above and the recommendation.

Comment: The Corrected version still gives me a blank write.txt
and the other version gives me an IOException saying cannot run program "javap":CreateProcess error=2.

Comment: You'll have to lean to compile your own code. I can't do much for you in that regard. Here's a transcript of a session using that code ( you don't even need an editor to reproduce it ) https://gist.github.com/1063873

Comment: @Kazekage don't expect a solution that just works. Try to find what's wrong, yourself. Take the code and ideas and try to fix your code, or adjust it to your needs. People won't spoonfeed you. btw, the above works.

Comment: @OscarRyz thanks mate.It works fine now. Because I am working on Windows, I had to change the command String to String command = "cmd /c javap java.lang.String" to first start the command prompt and then execute the javap command. :)

Comment: @Kazekage I tested on windows too, it should've worked without the `cmd /c` but if it work now, the better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which should work:

```
        StringBuffer outStream = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer errStream = new StringBuffer();
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = runtime.exec(command);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        InputStream outIs = process.getInputStream();
        MonitorOutputThread sout = new MonitorOutputThread(outIs, outStream);
        sout.run();

        InputStream errIs = process.getErrorStream();
        MonitorOutputThread serr = new MonitorOutputThread(errIs, errStream);
        serr.run();

        while (sout.isAlive() || serr.isAlive()) {
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // ignore
            }
        }
```

And the code for MonitorOutputThread

```
private class MonitorOutputThread extends Thread {

    private final InputStream is;
    private final StringBuffer output;

    public MonitorOutputThread(InputStream is, StringBuffer output) {
        this.is = is;
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line);
                output.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
            }

            if (output.length() >= 1) {
                char lastChar = output.charAt(output.length() - 1);

                if (lastChar == '\n') {
                    output.deleteCharAt(output.length() - 1);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

This should catch both the standard output and standard error of the command.

Comment: I think this is too complex for an example. And I think you should join the threads too.

Comment: Yes, it is a little complex. And you are right about the join.

Answer (score 0):

DevDaily has a [simple example](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016) of how to work with `Process` class.
See the snippet:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = null;

        try {

            // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
            // using the Runtime exec method:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

or even check [this code](https://github.com/c00kiemon5ter/LuceneEval/blob/master/src/trec/TrecProcess.java) I've writen some time ago

Comment: I'm getting blank outputs to this code when I use it for the command javap java.lang.String on command prompt in Windows