# Saving console output to string in Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to save the output from my code that pulls up netstat through the command line into a string so I can use a printline for it? So that when I run it through np++ I can see the output there instead of through the command line?

```
class Netstat
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    { 
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"netstat\"");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Java != Javascript`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch and store output from a subprocess in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575299/fetch-and-store-output-from-a-subprocess-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec() return a Process object which has input, output and error streams. Just read the output&error into some StringWriter.